# Anemometer in liquid

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, measurements

Does anyone know if there's an anemometer for fluid flow, or any speed measuring apparatus, that can work in liquid? I am planning to use it to demonstrate natural convection circulation.

Answer (score 2):

An anemometer usage involves airflow along a horizontal plane (typically) as well as a large mass of low density fluid (air).

There are flow gauges for fluids which involve an impeller in a manner similar to an anemometer, but the flow is restricted to a pipe or similar cylindrical enclosure.

The impellers are of various forms, sometimes gear shaped, sometimes propeller or screw shaped. The angles or pitch of the blades of the propeller type provide for different rates of rotation specific to the flow to be measured.

[Prusa Printables](https://www.printables.com/model/159163-elliptical-blade-naca-airfoil-propeller-library) has provided this image:

[image: various propeller shapes]

I am envisioning a visual means to display movement of fluid in a larger enclosure than that of the flow gauge, perhaps an aquarium or larger. If specific measurement is not required, this means that no data other than visual can be provided by a set of (for example) radio-control boat propellers, each one set to register flow on the three axis.

[image: xyz prop alignment]

Image personally created.

Anecdote: approximately at the turn of the century, I had a speedometer for my kayak. It was comprised of a very tiny low-friction propeller mounted on the hull. Directly above, inside the hull was the display unit. A magnet in the hub of the propeller (to reduce moment arm mass) rotated with water flow and was detected by the display unit.

Such a propeller might work for your circumstances, but having raw data may not be as practical. If that is an absolute requirement, a reflective tab on one of the blades could be read by an optical tachometer external to the enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a calibrated orifice and a U tube manometer as long as the pressure difference is large enough to be apparent on the scale.